# How to add numbers in a range

Tags: python, list, project, addition

Hey so I'm trying to do a challenge to add every number in multiples of 3 or 5 under 1000, and when I put in this code:

```
for x in xrange(1000):
if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0:
    place = list([x])
    sum(place)
```

it just lists all the numbers that are multiples of 3 and 5, is there any way I can add all the numbers that it lists?

Comment: `sum(x for x in xrange(1000) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are not retaining any value through each iteration of your loop. Your loop would be fixed with:

```
place = []
for x in range(1000):
    if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0:
        place.append(x)
sum(place)
```

Or just calculated along the way:

```
result = 0
for x in range(1000):
    if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0:
        result += x
result
```

As pointed out, a simple generator expression would solve the problem:

```
sum(x for x in range(1000) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0)
```

Note: I use Py3 - in Py2 `xrange()` would be an optimisation by avoiding the `list` construction of `range()`.

But there is a closed form for `sum(range(n+1))`:

```
s(n) = n * (n + 1) // 2
```

e.g.:

```
sum([0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 999]) == 999 * 1000 // 2 == 499500
```

Which can be extended to `sum(range(0, n+1, c))` as:

```
s(n, c) = c * (n//c) * (n//c + 1) // 2
```

e.g.:

```
sum([0, 3, 6, 9, ..., 999]) == 3 * (999//3) * (999//3 + 1) // 2 == 166833
```

So you can rewrite the problem as `s(999, 3) + s(999, 5) - s(999, 15)`, you must subtract `s(999, 15)` or you double count all the values that are divisible by both `3` and `5`, e.g.:

```
In []:
n = 1000
s = lambda n, c: c  * (n//c) * (n//c + 1) // 2
s(n-1, 3) + s(n-1, 5) - s(n-1, 15)

Out[]:
233168
```

This is `O(1)` vs `O(n)` for all the various `sum` approaches proposed.

Comment: @ChristianDean, I appreciate the effort to improve the answer, however, I chose to roll back the edit. While it is obvious the OP is using Py2.X, the question is not specifically tagged as Py2 and `range()` works in both Py2 and Py3. I will make a note to use `xrange()` in Py2.

Comment: Fair enough. Just thought you may want to use `xrange` since OP used it, and `xrange` is more like Python3's `range`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than testing each number between 0 and 1000 to see if it's a multiple of either 3 or 5, then summing those, generate a `set` that only contains multiples of 3 or 5 between 0 and 1000.

```
nums = set(range(3, 1000, 3))
nums.update(range(5, 1000, 5))
total = sum(nums)
```

Much more efficient to just not generate the numbers you don't want in the first place.

(A `set` is needed because some numbers are multiples of both 3 and 5 and the set will automatically include these only once. Also note our ranges omit 0 entirely since it doesn't affect the sum. Just a tiny bit more efficiency.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
total=0
for x in xrange(1000):
    if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0:
        total += x
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a great case for list comprehension:

```
total = sum([x for x in xrange(1000) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0])
```

**Edit**: It doesn't even need to be a list in this case (and I would imagine more efficient because [correct me if I'm wrong] the summing a generator only traverses the range once whereas the first would traverse the original range, create a range, then traverse it again to get the sum):

```
total = sum(x for x in xrange(1000) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0)
```

Comment: The first would iterate over the range and create a list of just the values that are divisible by `3` and `5`, then iterate over that list to sum. The second would iterate over the generator which iterates over the range yielding values that are divisible by `3` or `5`. From a speed perspective the difference between the 2 approaches are negligible, from a space perspective the generator wins.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(set(range(0, 1000, 3) + range(0, 1000, 5)))
```

Create a list of the numbers in the range, stepping by the divisible number, then remove duplicates, sum the result.

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
sum((x for x in range(1000) if any((x % 3 == 0, x % 5 == 0))
```

or

```
# less brackets
sum((x for x in range(1000) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0)
```

Use of the generator ensures low memory usage even if range is in the quadrillions.